# How can I programmatically set the value of an Entries field type?

Tags: entries-field

I need to set programmatically the value of an Entries field type when I'm going to create a new entry from the admin form, after the form loads I'm searching for the entry I need to set in the Entries field, so I'm making something like `setAttribute('companyField', $companyEntry)` but it didn't work.

I need to find a way to set/lookup that value in the Entries field type so the user can see it in the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For relationship fields (Entries, Assets, Users, Tags, etc.) you need to pass in an array of element IDs.

Something like this should work.

```
$entry->setAttribute('companyField', array($companyEntry->id));
```

Comment: cool, that works fine, i'll mark your answer as correct but could you tell me how can i do if i'm creating a new entry, i mean, i don't know how can i get the fields from that new entry i'm about to create. thanks

Comment: for entries that are currently created i can use the entryId to get the entry and update that entry field, but in this case i don't have an entryId

Comment: I don't know your front-end workflow, but either a user is selecting an already existing entry for the relationship to work, or your plugin is creating it at runtime before you save it, so your main `$entry` should have knowledge of it.