# Set User's entry field from PHP in Craft 3

Tags: craft3, entries, users, usermodel

From [this](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/16593/how-can-i-programmatically-set-the-value-of-an-entries-field-type) question, I tried:

```
$user->setAttributes(['products' => $userProductsIds]);

return Craft::$app->getElements()->saveElement($user);
```

Where `$user` is an instance of `craft\elements\User;` and `$userProductsIds` an array. It's not giving me any errors, but the user is not updated. Any idea on what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By checking `vendor/craftcms/cms/src/controllers/UsersController.php` and `vendor/craftcms/cms/src/base/Element.php`, I did it like

```
$user->setFieldValue('products', $userProductsIds);
return Craft::$app->getElements()->saveElement($user, false);
```